# Upgrade Suggestion for SharePoint On-premise 2013 Server Log shipping with DR Environment

Tags: sharepoint-server

Customer Environment : SP2013 Environment.

SP2013 WITH SP1 - April Version. It is integrated with Log shipping mode. Currently it is maintained as a DR Environment.

Now they want to upgrade the Patch to DEC 2021 Directly. They want to apply the Patch to Data center-1 but not for DR center. So is there any impact on the data or not?

If one Datacenter applied the patch to Dec 2021, will it impact the data break or functionality break on Production Environment, please provide your guidance on this query.

Currently customer does not have any Test environment to test it.

2nd Query:
Can customer Patch upgrade from April 2013 to Dec 2021 directly? is there issues.
or It is mandatory to install all patches from April 2013 later to Dec 2021.

Thanks in Advance for your response...!

Answer (score 0):

If the databases in the DR location are *not* attached to the DR SharePoint farm, there is no impact, however they will not be able to mount those databases to the DR SharePoint farm until the DR SharePoint farm is updated to the same patch level.

Yes, you can go directly from SP1 (or SP1 + later CU) to the most current CU.